# Serving images from google cloud storage in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing a google app engine application where users will upload photos and then i will have to serve the photos resized. I spent tons of hours researching what's the best solution and decided that gcs is the way to go. This is my code for uploading:

```
img_upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/list', gs_bucket_name='myapp.appspot.com/'+user_name))
```

This works and I can see in the developer's console the files being uploaded under the user_name folder.

This is my code for serving, that does not work:

```
gs_key = blobstore.create_gs_key('/gs/myapp.appspot.com/' + user_name + "/" + str(upload_files[0].key()))
imgSrc = images.get_serving_url(gs_key, size=385)
```

I get **ObjectNotFoundError** in get_serving_url. What's the way to do it?

Comment: No, i'm using python. Maybe java is similar, so any advice is greatly appreciated as i'm blocked on this for hours.

Comment: were you able to see the object in the development server datastore?

Comment: I can see the object in the blobstore in the local development server, but i can't serve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently updated [this GIST](https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133), where I show how to upload and serve files using the GCS client library for GAE Python.

In the examples I use the default bucket to store the the blobs. The default bucket has free quota.

Comment: Great tutorial, it solved my problem! Also, instead of the annoying _blobstore.create_upload_url()_, which I had to call for each html upload form, i have only a clean <form action="/gcs_upload">. I also don't store the images both in blobstore and gcs, which is also nice.

Answer (score 1):

A key is an object.  I think you want `upload_files[0].key.id()`

Comment: BlobKey has no id (method or property). The docs say _You can get the string form of a BlobKey value by passing it to the str() builtin._ . If I try images.get_serving_url(str(upload_files[0].key.id), size=385), then it works, but i guess it's serving it from the blobstore, not from the gcs since it's bypassing create_gs_key.

Comment: Where is `upload_files` defined?  Try logging `str(upload_files[0].key.id)` and `gs_key` to see their values

Comment: my class is derived from blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandlerupload_files, and upload_files = self.get_uploads(). There is no key.id nor key.id(), so i can't log that one. gs_key is just a (very long) encoded string.

Comment: This might be an issue with eventual consistency.  Write a separate script to get the image, and run it 30 seconds after you put it.  Perhaps it is not yet put in the datastore when you try to fetch it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `java`, here is what i am doing,

while uploading,

```
bucketName = "mainBucket/subFolder/subFolder/subFolder";
objectName = "fileName";


gcsService.createOrReplace(new GcsFilename(bucketName, objectName), ....{other arguments} )
```

while serving it,

```
gsBlobkey  = createGsBlobKey("/gs/"+bucketName+"/"+objectName");
imageURl   = serveFromBlobKey(gsBlobkey);
```

In development server datastore, there will be a entity named `__GsFileInfo__`. in that there will be a field named `fileName`. make sure the url you are forming and the `fileName` are same.